# How to display PHP on the same html page

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have a HTML form where I can search through a MySQL database using PHP. After running the PHP code I get the search result on another page. I would like to get the search result in a table next to the form. Code below:

HTML:

```
 <form name="select"action="select.php" method="post">
 Name:
 <input type="submit" name="sub">
 </form>
```

PHP:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db where name ='$name'";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
        echo "<table>"; //tabellen
        echo "<table border=1";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Email</th>";
                echo "<th>Name</th>";
                echo "<th>nbr</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['nbr'] . "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Comment: Use ajax to send the request and manipulate the dom when it gets the response or set the form action to the same page and have the PHP code in the same page

Comment: Try with an AJAX call or a $.load() by jquery

Comment: These links should be able to help https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_php.asp || http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Your html is invalid - you have `<table><table border=1` ~ unclosed and nested incorrectly

Comment: either ajax or put your entire code in the same file/page and set the action to self.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option would be to have the php code that processes the search request on the same page and remove the form action.

That said your code is vulnerable to SQL injection due to the embedded variables within the sql statement. As you are using `mysqli` you should easily be able to translate this to use `prepared statements` like:

Example:

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['name'] ) ) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    /*
        Better to select specific fields rather than all fields, 
        then bind those to specific result variables.
    */
    $sql='select `email`,`name`,`nbr` from `db` where `name`=?';
    $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );

    if( $stmt ){

        $stmt->bind_param( 's', $name );
        $result=$stmt->execute();

        if( $result && $stmt->num_rows > 0 ){

            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result( $email, $name, $nbr );

            echo '<table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>nbr</th>
                    </tr>';

            while( $stmt->fetch() ){
                printf('
                    <tr>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                    </tr>', $email, $name, $nbr );
            }

            echo '</table>';
        }
    }
}
```

To do it with ajax then something along these lines perhaps ( where `select.php` has the above code or similar )

```
document.querySelector('sub').onclick=function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var _callback=function(r){
        document.querySelector('form[name="select"]').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',r);
    }

    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )_callback.call( this, this.response );
    }
    xhr.open( 'POST', 'select.php', true );
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send( 'name='+document.querySelector('name').value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
search.php

<form name="select" action="" method="post">
 Name:
 <input type="submit" name="sub">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db where name ='$name'";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<table border=1">;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>nbr</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['nbr'] . "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_free_result($result);
}
?>
```